# Session variables not carrying to next page

Tags: php, session

I've just begun using sessions and am having some headaches, I had this working last night, now opening it today...no longer works.

In my login processor I have the following if everything is OK. This script works fine, I have echoed the session variables to ensure that the array works, and it does.

```
$username - > post from login script
$encrypt_password -> created from password check further up the script      

        {

                    $session_name = 'LOGIN'; // Set a custom session name
                    $secure = false; // Set to true if using https.
                    $httponly = true; // This stops javascript being able to access the session id. 
                    $cookie_lifetime = '3600';
                    $cookie_path = '/';
                    $cookie_domain = '127.0.0.1';

                    session_set_cookie_params($cookie_lifetime, $cookie_path, $cookie_domain, $secure, $httponly); 
                    session_name($session_name); // Sets the session name to the one set above.

                    $group = $row['group_type'];

                    $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; /*grabs browser info*/

                    $user_id = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", "", $username); /*XSS Protection*/
                    $group_id = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", "", $group);   /*XSS Protection*/

                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['user']=$user_id;
                    $_SESSION['group_name']=$group_id;
                    $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', $user_browser.$encrypt_password);
                    session_write_close();

                    header("location:".$group_id."_index.php");                         
                }
```

I have created an include file which gathers the info from the session, included on every protected page, this is where it fell apart. I have created custom error codes for each if statement and have found that the if statement here fails. Echoing the session variables or evening printing the session array returns nothing.

```
 $session_name = 'LOGIN'; // Set a custom session name
        $secure = false; // Set to true if using https.
        $httponly = true; // This stops javascript being able to access the session id. 
        $cookie_lifetime = '3600';
        $cookie_path = '/';
        $cookie_domain = '127.0.0.1';

        session_set_cookie_params($cookie_lifetime, $cookie_path, $cookie_domain, $secure, $httponly); 
        session_name($session_name); // Sets the session name to the one set above.
        session_start(); // Start the php session
        session_regenerate_id(false); // regenerated the session, delete the old one.     

    if(isset($_SESSION['user'],$_SESSION['group_name'], $_SESSION['login_string']))
```

I was changing around the way the user groups worked before this broke, however none of the variables make it through. I am learning from his tut by the way: [create a secure login script in php and mysql](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL)

Also do I need to call the session parameters every time a user visits a protected page?

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: Try putting `session_start();` on TOP of everything, most importantly before you're calling a session. You're calling `session_name($session_name);` before it even started. `it=session`

Comment: Any pages that use session variable need to call in your case need to call at least session_name (with the same parameter as the session was initially set with) and session_start

Comment: @fred make that an answer, above session_name I had a connection call, moving that below session_start fixed the issue. Thanks

Comment: @Owen Ok, thanks. I will. Glad it worked out for you, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting `session_start();` on TOP of everything, most importantly before you're calling a session. You're calling `session_name($session_name);` before it even started.

`it=session`

Answer (score 0):

your regenerating the session on every page, which causes the previous session to destroy data.

remove `session_regenerate_id(false);`